# json api is not responding when query string with space is provided [carqueryapi]

Tags: jquery, json, api

i am actually working with the carqueryapi to get vehicle data everything works fine except when pass a query string with space.so i mean when you pass query like :

```
www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&make=subaru&year=2010
```

it works perfect but when you try to pass make or model with space between it does not work

```
www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&make=aston martin&year=2010
```

Things i have tried:

1. using %20 & %2b for space in string but not worked
2. i even tried to encode url that dosen't work
3. using data params dosen't work for e.g data:[make:make,model:model]

   $('#select2').change(function(){

   if(!$('#select2 option:selected').is(':first-child'))
   {
              cleardisable(1);

   ```
       year = $('#select option:selected').text();
       make = $('#select2 option:selected').text();

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&make="+make+"&year="+year,
          dataType: "json",

        beforeSend: function() {
               $('#aloading').show();
           },
          success: function(data) {

             $('#select3').empty();
             $('#select3').append('<option>Select Model...</option>');
             $(data.Models).each(function(index,value){
               $('#select3').append('<option value=\"'+value.model_name+'\">'+value.model_name+'</option>');
            });

             $('#select3').removeAttr('disabled');
             $('#aloading').hide();
          }
       });
   ```

   }
    else
    {
           cleardisable(1);
    }
   });

please need your help whats wrong in here thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `+` instead of `%20`?

Comment: So they haven't implemented it so that it works with `aston martin` as the make. Maybe they've implemented it as something else, e.g. `aston_martin`, `AstonMartin`, `Aston-Martin`, etc. Or maybe it simply isn't in their database. If they really are requiring you to guess then they're doing it wrong. Do they have anything more useful, like a search feature? Or can you find any examples where the name of the make has spaces?

Comment: yeah david you are right they using (-) hyphen Aston-Martin instead of space i am working with json for the first time so i didnt know what was wrong thanx to you problem solved

Comment: @DavidKnipe no guessing. Looking at the api documentation: you first make a query that returns a list of make (ids). Then you may make subsequent queries using the proper make (id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query parameter `make` takes a `-` in place of space:

http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getTrims&make=aston-martin&year=2010

however the `make` parameter should not be used as an arbitrary search string.

It is actually an **id**: you find it in JSON responses as value for the key `"make-id"`